# Sum needed for MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, join, relational-database, outer-join

I hope you can help me with the following query:
I have the following 2 tables:

[image: tableA]

[image: table]

tableA.currencyA will always be = to the currencyB in the related item in tableB.
I need to return the following results:

[image]

Basically in the results I need to return all items in tableA + a summary of the entries in tableB. I have been trying several queries but it looks like I cannot come out with a sentences for this. The ones I've tried were not returning the data for item4 (note that item4 does not have entries in tableB).

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: Please read & act on How to Ask, the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Show what you tried. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little clean approach to what you need to

```
SELECT z.*,
(z.totalA - z.in) AS difference
FROM (
    SELECT a.idA, a.currencyA, a.totalA,
    IF(b.idB IS NOT NULL, SUM(b.amountA), 0) AS `in`
    FROM tableA a
    LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.idA = b.idA
    GROUP BY a.idA
) z;
```

> Output

```
idA currencyA   totalA  in  difference
1      usd       1000   550   450
2      usd       2000   700   1300
3      eur       3000   600   2400
4      usd       4000    0    4000
```

[Working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40e9f/14/0)

Comment: Thanks Samir! The query you posted works great. Do you know if there's any difference in terms of performance between your query and the one I've posted below? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49157229/1835537

Comment: In your query, it will calculate `SUM` and check 'IF/ELSE' condition twice which is not a performance bottleneck, but can be simplified and little more optimized with the one I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this would work ok:

```
select 
    tableA.idA, 
    tableA.currencyA as currency, 
    tableA.totalA as total, 
    case when (sum(tableB.amountB) is null) then 0 else sum(tableB.amountB) end as 'in',
    case when (sum(tableB.amountB) is null) then tableA.totalA else 
    tableA.totalA-sum(tableB.amountB) end as 'difference'
from 
    tableA left outer join tableB on tableA.idA=tableB.idA
group by tableA.idA;
```